# Font-family defaults to sans-serif alternative

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Here is my CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Istok Web';
    src: url(fonts/fonts_istok-web/IstokWeb-Regular.ttf);
}

 body {
      font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif !important;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #000;
      background-color:#fff;
  }
```

If I remove the sans-serif alternative, the imported font works fine. However, with the code above, the browser automatically defaults to sans-serif. I've done this with and without the !important tag. In fact, if I add anything after 'Istok Web' it switches to sans-serif.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  .ttf files won't always render properly in every browser.

Comment: I've tried it in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, and it's the same in all of them.

Comment: If you add a different font between 'Istok Web' and sans-serif does it pick that font or still sans-serif? Do you have a working example you can show using jsfiddle (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure to check your file paths.  The `src` is relative to the path of the CSS file which is easy to get wrong.  According to your code you have `/fonts/` in the same directory as your CSS file.  Is that correct?
2. Add `format("truetype")` like the example below. You should really have different font files to ensure cross-browser compatibility.  There are services online that will do these conversions for free.
3. If all else fails, double-check your server MIME types to ensure the font extensions are allowed.

This is the format I've used numerous times and it always seems to work fine.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Archer-Medium";
    src: url("../fonts/archer-medium-pro.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url("../fonts/archer-medium-pro.svg#ArcherMedium") format("svg"), 
         url("../fonts/archer-medium-pro.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("../fonts/archer-medium-pro.ttf") format("truetype");
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Archer-Medium",Georgia,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: The file path isn't the problem... if I remove "sans-serif" the font works. It's just that when I include it it automatically defaults to it. So adding the truetype format didn't do anything.

Comment: Do you have a hosted example we can take a look at?  Have you tried using Chrome's DevTools or Firebug to try and troubleshoot?

Answer (score -2):

What browser are you using? Have you tested in multiple browsers and noticed this issue consistently? Sometimes browsers can have issues with capitalization or spacing in the font URL.

Also, you don't need quotes when defining the font-family in @font-face. That can lead to mixed results. Try this CSS instead:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IstokWeb;
    src: url(fonts/fonts_istok-web/IstokWeb-Regular.ttf);
}
body {
    font-family: IstokWeb, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif ;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #000;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

If that doesn't work, I would recommend renaming your folders and ttf file to lowercase and using this CSS:

```
src: url(fonts/fonts_istok-web/istokweb-regular.ttf);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried all of these but without any luck.

Comment: Do you need to host the font file yourself? If not, that font is also available through [Google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Istok+Web). It may be worth trying to add it that way and see if you still have issues.

Comment: It worked through Google fonts previously, but I would rather host it.